# The difference between two dates in Hiveql

Tags: sql, hive, sas, hiveql

I wish to find the differences between two dates in **date format** in Hiveql. I used the blow function in SAS to return a date value by subtracting a number

```
intnx('day', 20MAR2019 , -7)
```

It subtracts 7 days from the date and returns 13MAR2019

I wish to convert it to Hiveql language. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: please provide your table structure with some sample data and expected results

Comment: Thanks @vikrant in SAS if you write this code 'intnx('day', 20MAR2019 , -7);'         it subtracts 7 days from the date and return '13MAR2019'! I'm looking for the same function in Hiveql

Comment: I have updated the question to be more clear!

Comment: I have also updated the answer with some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use date_sub function in hive to subtract the days from a given date.

```
hive> select current_date;
2019-07-25
hive> select date_sub(current_date,7);
2019-07-18
```

This will return null.

```
hive> select date_sub('13MAR2019',7);
OK
NULL
```

since your date is format 'ddMMMYYY', you can convert it yyy-MM-dd format.

```
hive> select date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('13MAR2019' ,'ddMMMyyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),7);
OK
2019-03-06
```

Comment: Thanks @vikrant It was the answer that I was looking for